Помогите решить ошибку A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty
import telebot
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
loc = Nominatim(user_agent="GetLoc")
hospitals =["Воронеж","воронеж"]
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
def last_br(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Для начала напишите /start",parse_mode="html")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def last_breath(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"<b>Здравствуйте , вас приветствует телеграм бот 'Спектр диагностики' , здесь вы мсожете ознакомиться с нашими услугами и узнать контактные данные :)</b>",parse_mode="html")
@bot.message_handler(commands=["location"])
def have_hospital(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Отправьте название вашего города",parse_mode="html")
   bot.register_next_step_handler(message,city)
def city(message):

   cityt = message.text

   if cityt in hospitals:
      getLoc = loc.geocode("Спектр диагностика ," + cityt)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,getLoc,parse_mode="")

         

   else:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Извините , но нет :( ",parse_mode="html")
     
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

